# Function scopes in regards with includes in PHP

Tags: php, function, include, scope

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding includes and function scopes in PHP, and a bit of Googling hasn't provided successful results. But here is the problem:

This does not work:

```
function include_a(){
    // Just imagine some complicated code
    if(isset($_SESSION['language'])){
        include 'left_side2.php';
    } else {
        include 'left_side.php';
    }
    // More complicated code to determine which file to include
}

function b() {
    include_a();
    print_r($lang); // Will say that $lang is undefined
}
```

So essentially, there is an array called `$lang` in `left_side.php` and `left_side2.php`. I want to access it inside `b()`, but the code setup above will say that `$lang` is undefined. However, when I copy and paste the exact code in `include_a()` at the very beginning of `b()`, it will work fine. But as you can imagine, I do not wish to copy and paste the code in every function that I need it.

How can I alleviate this scope issue and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array `$lang` gets defined inside the `include_a()` function, it is scoped to that function only, even if that function is called inside `b()`.  To access `$lang` inside `b()` you need to call it globally.

This happens because you `include 'left_side2.php';` inside the `include_a()` function.  If there are several variables defined inside the includes and you want them to be at global scope, then you will need to define them as such.

Inside the `left_side.php`, define them as:

```
$GLOBALS['lang'] = whatever...;
```

Then in the function that calls them, try this:

```
function b() {
    include_a();
    print_r($GLOBALS['lang']); // Now $lang should be known.
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was unaware of the $GLOBALS feature. Though calling an associative $GLOBALS has a quirky syntax (i.e $GLOBALS['lang']['EMAIL']), but all is well. Now there's no need for the include_a() function either.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered 'bad practice' to use globals where you don't have to (not a consideration I subscribe to, but generally accepted).  The better practice is to pass by reference by adding an ampersand in front of the passed variable so you can edit the value.

So inside left_side or left_side2 you would have:

```
b($lang);
```

and b would be:

```
function b(&$lang){...}
```

For further definitions on variable scopes [check this out](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Well, editing those files requires a major overhaul if I were to do it that way, so I'm afraid that's not so viable. However, to alleviate the issue of the weird `$GLOBALS['array']['property']` syntax, I can just define, at the top of each function, `global $lang`, and then access `$lang` as normal (as shown in your link, thanks). Is one way better than the other, or are they both the same performance-wise?

Comment: I haven't run any tests to be certain but I imagine the difference would be insignificant since they are both calling the global reference of an existing variable (as opposed to instantiating a new copy).